# loopback converts date like strings to Date, how to prevent it

Tags: strongloop, loopback

I have a soap service returning datetime (to check for optimistic lock later)
this is what I receive if I call the soap service in postman

```
            <ns2:outcomes>
                <ns2:outcomeId>18743</ns2:outcomeId>
                <ns2:outcomeName>sadfagdadg</ns2:outcomeName>
                <ns2:channelsId>4</ns2:channelsId>
                <ns2:createdBy>tstsdm01</ns2:createdBy>
                <ns2:createdTimestamp>2020-02-20T10:22:55.035222000-05:00</ns2:createdTimestamp>
                <ns2:editedBy>tstsdm01</ns2:editedBy>
                <ns2:editedTimestamp>2020-02-20T10:22:55.035222000-05:00</ns2:editedTimestamp>
                <ns2:status>ACT</ns2:status>
            </ns2:outcomes>
```

Then I generated the model by `lb soap` and this is the model

```
{
  "name": "OutcomeType",
  "base": "Model",
  "idInjection": false,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "forceId": "false",
  "excludeBaseProperties": [
    "id"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "outcomeId": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "outcomeName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "channelsId": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "listOrder": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "createdBy": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "createdTimestamp": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "editedBy": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "editedTimestamp": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "status": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

Then I call the same endpoint as REST api via loopback
What I receive is

```
        {
            "outcomeId": 18743,
            "outcomeName": "sadfagdadg",
            "channelsId": 4,
            "createdBy": "tstsdm01",
            "createdTimestamp": "2020-02-20T15:22:55.035Z",
            "editedBy": "tstsdm01",
            "editedTimestamp": "2020-02-20T15:22:55.035Z",
            "status": "ACT"
        },
```

the precision of date is changed, I just want to treat the value as string not as datetime

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody else has same problem

There is is code in `strong-soap` library, and it works by contract of type name in wsdl file (url)

[image]

So if the type name is `date` or `time` or `dateTime` it will convert it to javascript `Date`, doesn't matter whta is your model data type.

To solve that I downloaded the wsdl from url and store it in the project, then I changed `dateTime` to `string` in the downloaded file.

In my `datasources.json`

```
  "outcome": {
    "url": "http://localhost:8080/gateway-ws/services/outcome-v1",
    "name": "outcome",
    "wsdl": "server/wsdl/outcome-v1.wsdl.xml",
    "remotingEnabled": true,
    "connector": "soap"
  },
```

Comment: Thanks. The strong-soap implementation for the parsing has gotten completed overtime. I couldn't trace that same code in their library

Answer (score 0):

`xsd:date` requires you specify only the date eg `2021-11-25` without the time element.

The problem is that some xml handlers (like the one in `strong-soap`) that convert between SOAP and JSON treat `date` and `dateTime` the same way. So they convert the date string to `Date` and vice versa.

Now when you provide a `dateTime` when the SOAP server expects a `date`, the SOAP server can crash. This is because the `dateTime` value provided has that extra `T00:00:00.000Z` that the SOAP server wasn't expecting.

In my case, to resolve this, I modified the data type of the `date` field on the SOAP server to instead be a `dateTime`.